# Getting all fields of models declared in Mongo using Node Js with projection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having an model schema as

```
{  
 "payperhour":{type: "number",required : true},
"desgnid":{type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,required:true},
'createdat':{type:'Date',default:currendate},
'createdby':{type:'string'},
'modifiedby':{type:'string'},
'modifiedat':{type:'Date',default:currendate
}
```

by the help of unwind and project i am getting the data very well.

```
ot.aggregate([{$lookup:{
            from: "designations",
            localField: "desgnid",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "designation"
    }},{ $unwind : "$designation" },{ $project : { "desgnname" : "$designation.desgnname","payperhour":1,"desgnid":1}}],function(error,response){
            if(error){
                res.json(error)
            }
            else{
                console.log(response)
                res.json(response)
            }
        })
```

My query is instead of writing those field values again or making them true can we send all values rather than unwind values. Because for 2-3 fields writing is ok but for 100 fields it is a worse. Any Idea please let me. Not vote down for the question. Answer the question and later mark is as duplicate or vote down.

My required Output is

[image]

It should be in the following provided image format

Comment: $$Root is the point , just google it :)

Comment: @RITESHARORA thanks but no use. I already tried that document:"$$ROOT" this is also giving me the output but not in the way i want. I have edited my question with required output image